# Is it possible to round a number with Spring data MongoDB aggregations?

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following aggregation pipeline to calculate the top rated brands from a collection of phones with their reviews embedded.

```
public Document findTopRatedBrands(int minReviews, int results) {
        UnwindOperation unwindOperation = unwind("reviews");
        GroupOperation groupOperation = group("$brand").avg("$reviews.rating")
                        .as("avgRating").count().as("numReviews");
        MatchOperation matchOperation = match(new Criteria("numReviews").gte(minReviews));
        SortOperation sortOperation = sort(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "avgRating",
                "numReviews"));
        LimitOperation limitOperation = limit(results);
        ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = project().andExpression("_id").as
                ("brand").andExpression("avgRating").as("rating").andExclude("_id")
                .andExpression("numReviews").as("reviews");
        Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(unwindOperation, groupOperation, matchOperation,
                sortOperation, limitOperation, projectionOperation);
        AggregationResults<Phone> result = mongoOperations
                .aggregate(aggregation, "phones", Phone.class);
        return result.getRawResults();
    }
```

An example of document in the phones collection is this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61e1cc8f452d0aef89d9125f"
    },
    "brand": "Samsung",
    "name": "Samsung Galaxy S7",
    "releaseYear": 2016,
    "reviews": [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "61d4403b86913bee0245c171"
        },
        "rating": 2,
        "dateOfReview": {
            "$date": "2019-12-24T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "title": "Won't do that again.",
        "body": "I could not use with my carrier. Sent it back.",
        "username": "bigrabbit324"
    }]
}
```

I would like to sort by avgRating (rounded to the first decimal place), and secondly by the number of reviews. Now the average rating it's not rounded so it gives always different values, so I can't sort by number of reviews also. I have seen the ArithmeticOperators.Round class but I don't understand how to include it here if possible.

An example of result is the following:

```
[Document{{brand=Nokia, rating=3.25, reviews=4}}]
```

I would like to have 3.2 as rating.

This works in Mongo Compass:

```
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        brand: '$_id',
        rating: { $round: ['$avgRating', 1] }
    }
```

Comment: can you please post some sample data?

Comment: From new sample data, it sounds like your are trying to achieve something similar to this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/tS_6iwCvlur

your updating question mentions `$round` works in mongo compass, but your comment below mentions you got an error using `$round`.  Can you please clarify if `$round` is supported in your environment, your mongodb is a version >= 4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
ProjectionOperation roundAverageRating = Aggregation.project("avgRating", "numReviews")
    .and(ArithmeticOperators.Round.roundValueOf("avgRating").place(1))
    .as("avgRatingRounded");
```

Comment: I tried this but gives me the following error: org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Command failed with error 15999: 'exception: invalid operator '$round'' on server localhost

Comment: It looks like $round in [new in mongodb version 4.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/round/). What version mongodb are you running?

Comment: Thanks, I was using an older version for the unit tests (3.0.1), it works with MongoDB 5.0.5

Comment: Glad it is working